# Charged for a service I don't use - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

I'm using a service on google cloud platform that I don't know how to disable.

Here is the exact name of the service: Compute Engine Micro Instance with burstable CPU running in Americas: 1556.347 Hours. I think I found a service running under APIs & Services with the name "Compute Engine API" that is consistently running. I've tried turning this off, however I get this error when trying to turn off the api: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x7mM.png) . Could this be the incorrect thing to turn off?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not turn on the  Compute Engine API. That is not creating your bill. You have a Compute Engine instance running in one of your projects linked to your billing account. Log into the console and find it.

Comment: Have you solved this issue by following the comment above?

Comment: Not sure the exact command to use. But after using "gcloud compute instances list". It says "Listed 0 items."

Comment: Actually boss fixed problem last night, which might be why 0 is showing. He said the problem was actually a glitch. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Error was caused by a glitch. Needed to call google cloud support to resolve the issue.